# Change frequency timeseries in Pandas Series with tolerance, but keep original dates, removing duplicated new frequency dates with same values

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have time-series data with varying measurement frequencies. I want to transform the data to a frequency of more or less a amount of days. The resulting time-series can be irregular.

For example, I have this time-serie:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-02-16 | 26.17000 |
| 2017-02-27 | 26.28000 |
| 2017-03-13 | 26.30000 |
| 2017-03-29 | 26.23000 |
| 2017-04-14 | 26.19000 |
| 2017-04-26 | 26.06000 |
| 2017-05-13 | 26.06000 |
| 2017-05-27 | 25.65000 |
| 2017-06-16 | 25.29000 |
| 2017-07-05 | 25.25000 |
| 2017-07-14 | 25.48000 |
| 2017-07-26 | 25.57000 |
| 2017-08-17 | 25.16000 |
| 2017-08-28 | 25.33000 |
| 2017-09-12 | 25.68235 |
| 2017-09-13 | 25.83799 |
| 2017-09-14 | 25.76669 |
| 2017-09-15 | 25.85253 |
| 2017-09-16 | 25.82017 |
| 2017-09-17 | 25.78362 |
| 2017-09-18 | 25.88422 |
| 2017-09-19 | 25.89594 |
| 2017-09-20 | 25.85522 |
| 2017-09-21 | 25.83583 |
| 2017-09-22 | 25.80082 |
| 2017-09-23 | 25.80076 |
| 2017-09-24 | 25.79209 |
| 2017-09-25 | 25.80632 |
| 2017-09-26 | 25.77773 |
| 2017-09-27 | 25.76311 |

In the beginning the measurements are with a frequency of around 14 days. Later, the frequency is daily. I want to change this to a frequency of around 14 days, but I want to keep the dates.

I tried this:

```
serie.reindex(index=serie.asfreq('14d').index,method='nearest',tolerance=datetime.timedelta(3))
```

I got this as a result:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-02-16 | 26.17000 |
| 2017-03-02 | 26.28000 |
| 2017-03-16 | 26.30000 |
| 2017-03-30 | 26.23000 |
| 2017-04-13 | 26.19000 |
| 2017-04-27 | 26.06000 |
| 2017-05-11 | 26.06000 |
| 2017-05-25 | 25.65000 |
| 2017-06-08 | NaN |
| 2017-06-22 | NaN |
| 2017-07-06 | 25.25000 |
| 2017-07-20 | NaN |
| 2017-08-03 | NaN |
| 2017-08-17 | 25.16000 |
| 2017-08-31 | 25.33000 |
| 2017-09-14 | 25.76669 |
| 2017-09-28 | 25.73150 |

This is more or less what I want. The values in column "Value" is what I'm looking for. Only I want the original dates corresponding with the values. How can I do this? Thank you very much in advance! This is the result I want:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-02-16 | 26.17000 |
| 2017-02-27 | 26.28000 |
| 2017-03-13 | 26.30000 |
| 2017-03-29 | 26.23000 |
| 2017-04-14 | 26.19000 |
| 2017-04-26 | 26.06000 |
| 2017-05-13 | 26.06000 |
| 2017-05-27 | 25.65000 |
| 2017-06-08 | NaN |
| 2017-06-22 | NaN |
| 2017-07-05 | 25.25000 |
| 2017-07-20 | NaN |
| 2017-08-03 | NaN |
| 2017-08-17 | 25.16000 |
| 2017-08-28 | 25.33000 |
| 2017-09-14 | 25.76669 |
| 2017-09-28 | 25.73150 |

Comment: Running the code you tried, I don't get the last row entry of date `2017-09-28`.  Could you please check ?

Comment: I'm sorry @SeaBean, that's because I didn't show the complete input data, only the relevant (I thought). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem @hotoats.  See if my solution works for your complete data.  Just let me know after reviewing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build an intermediate working dataframe containing reindexed rows and original rows to facilitate copying dates from old indexes to dates in new indexes. Then, filter rows and copy dates for selected indexes.

**Step 1:** Build a dataframe containing reindexed rows and original rows:

We can use [`Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) to get a union of reindexed indexes and original indexes, as follows:

```
idx_new = serie.asfreq('14d').index
idx_old = serie.index
idx_all = idx_new.union(idx_old)

tolerance = 3

serie_all = serie.reindex(index=idx_all, method='nearest', tolerance=datetime.timedelta(tolerance))
```

**Step 2:** Filter rows and copy dates for selected indexes:

Let's use [`numpy.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to filter for multiple conditions. Then, keep only rows with index not `NaN`/`NaT` using `.loc`:

Filtering conditions:

- For dates not in new reindexed index, mask to `NaT` for discard
- For date where its immediate previous date entry is in original index, and the column `Value` have same values, the 2 dates differ less than or equal to tolerance (3 days)  ==>  Change reindexed date to the immediate previous date entry
- Similar checking for the immediate following date entry  ==>  Change reindexed date to the immediate following date entry
- Otherwise, keep the new reindexed date indexes

```
condlist = [~ serie_all.index.isin(idx_new),
            serie_all.index.to_series().shift().isin(idx_old) & serie_all['Value'].eq(serie_all['Value'].shift()) & serie_all.index.to_series().diff().dt.days.le(tolerance),
            serie_all.index.to_series().shift(-1).isin(idx_old) & serie_all['Value'].eq(serie_all['Value'].shift(-1)) & serie_all.index.to_series().diff(-1).dt.days.abs().le(tolerance),
            True
           ]

choicelist = [pd.NaT,
              serie_all.index.to_series().shift(),
              serie_all.index.to_series().shift(-1),
              serie_all.index,
             ]

# Change date index values based on conditions
serie_all.index = pd.to_datetime(np.select(condlist, choicelist))

# Keep only non-NaT rows
serie_final = serie_all.loc[serie_all.index.notna()].rename_axis(index='Date')
```

**Result:**

```
print(serie_final)


               Value
Date                
2017-02-16  26.17000
2017-02-27  26.28000
2017-03-13  26.30000
2017-03-29  26.23000
2017-04-14  26.19000
2017-04-26  26.06000
2017-05-13  26.06000
2017-05-27  25.65000
2017-06-08       NaN
2017-06-22       NaN
2017-07-05  25.25000
2017-07-20       NaN
2017-08-03       NaN
2017-08-17  25.16000
2017-08-28  25.33000
2017-09-14  25.76669
```

---

**Data Setup**

```
data = {'Value': {pd.Timestamp('2017-02-16 00:00:00'): 26.17,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-02-27 00:00:00'): 26.28,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-03-13 00:00:00'): 26.3,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-03-29 00:00:00'): 26.23,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-04-14 00:00:00'): 26.19,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-04-26 00:00:00'): 26.06,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-05-13 00:00:00'): 26.06,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-05-27 00:00:00'): 25.65,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-06-16 00:00:00'): 25.29,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-07-05 00:00:00'): 25.25,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-07-14 00:00:00'): 25.48,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-07-26 00:00:00'): 25.57,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-08-17 00:00:00'): 25.16,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-08-28 00:00:00'): 25.33,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-12 00:00:00'): 25.68235,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-13 00:00:00'): 25.83799,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-14 00:00:00'): 25.76669,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-15 00:00:00'): 25.85253,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-16 00:00:00'): 25.82017,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-17 00:00:00'): 25.78362,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-18 00:00:00'): 25.88422,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-19 00:00:00'): 25.89594,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-20 00:00:00'): 25.85522,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-21 00:00:00'): 25.83583,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-22 00:00:00'): 25.80082,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-23 00:00:00'): 25.80076,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-24 00:00:00'): 25.79209,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-25 00:00:00'): 25.80632,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-26 00:00:00'): 25.77773,
  pd.Timestamp('2017-09-27 00:00:00'): 25.76311}}  
  
serie = pd.DataFrame(data).rename_axis(index='Date')
```

Comment: Hi SeaBean, thanks for your help and quick reply. Unfortunately, this is not the result I'm looking for. I edited my post to be more clear.

Comment: @hotoats  Edited solution for your question update.  Please take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much. It almost works perfectly. An addition: I have one suggestion for improvement, in the third condition you compare the days with the tolerance. The days have a negative value, so the condition is always True. I think we take the absolute value, like: serie_all.index.to_series().diff(-1).dt.days.abs().le(tolerance). Agree?

Comment: @hotoats  Yes, that's right.  My original thought included this but missed it out when typing it in.  Thanks for reminding this.  :-)   Another example that a complete set of testing data is important to ensure our programs logics are correct in every cases :-)